# Listening on a port outside of ASP.NET framework in a elastic beanstalk .NET app

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ASP.NET application and I have a library I need to use that also runs a simple http server inside of this app.

This works fine when I build and run locally.

However, when I upload to elastic beanstalk it simply doesn't work.

Is there something elastic beanstalk expects that only works if ports are opened through the ASP.NET framework?

I am at a bit of a loss as to why this is not working.

Expected:

- I can run a .NET Core app within elastic beanstalk and listen on ports the same way I do locally.

Actual:

- Unable to receive messages on other ports.

I have tried not starting the asp dot net host and starting it, either way the result is the same. The ASP.NET endpoints work fine, the other websockets do not.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 'other ports.' - which ports? 'this is not working' - what doesn't work?